# Error while configuring View Resolver for mustache template engine

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, mustache

I have the following configuration file in spring-boot project :

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver mustacheViewResolver() {
        MustacheViewResolver viewResolver = new MustacheViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".mustache");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

When I run my application, I am getting the following error: 
Description:

The bean 'mustacheViewResolver', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mustache/MustacheServletWebConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/AppConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

I am not sure if I am configuring the view Resolver properly

**Error after removing the configuration class:**

```
o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected '*/*' given [*/*]
o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'tweets.mustache', model {tweets=null}
o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [tweets.mustache]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/tweets.mustache?email=tim@gmail.com", parameters={masked}
 o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
 o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?email=tim@gmail.com", parameters={masked}
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=, status=404, error=Not Found, path=/tweet2}]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

```
 @GetMapping("/tweet2")
    public ModelAndView getTweetsByEmail(@RequestParam String email) {
        HQLExample.insertRecords();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("tweets.mustache");
        List<Tweet> tweets = tweetMap.get(email);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("tweets",tweets);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: Remove this class. Restart application. Spring Boot automatically picks up and configures Mustache when found, your bean interferes with that.

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed the class. It gives an error. I have put tweets.mustache file under `resources` folder.  It seems it is not able to find the resource. FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/tweets.mustache? <-- This line is weird why is it making a GET to /tweets.mustache

Comment: It should be in `src/main/resources/templates/` and the name of the view is `tweets` the `.mustache` part is added automatically. I also assume you have `spring-boot-starter-mustache` as a dependency.

Comment: @M.Deinum Wow! That worked. Thanks a lot. So spring-boot is automatically configured to pick up templates from this folder. The resources folder is a special folder the same way the `templates` folder is also automatically configured by spring boot to look for template files. Is that correct?  Or it's like it adds this to the classpath?

Comment: @M.Deinum Please add that as a solution, so that I can accept

Comment: `src/main/resources` is basically the root of the classpath for non java files. Everything gets copied to `target/classes` (assuming you are using maven). For all view technologies it uses the `/templates` directory in the root of the classpath as the location to find the templates. Depending on the type a prefix is added (thymeleaf is .HTML, Mustache is .mustache etc. ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have added `spring-boot-starter-mustache` as a dependency (to easily include all needed dependencies). When Spring Boot detects Mustache on the classpath it will automatically configure the `MustacheViewResolver` which will load Mustache templates from `/templates` on the classpath. The files should end with `.mustache`.

With this in mind, just remove your `AppConfig` class as it interferes with the auto configuration.

In your controller the name of the view is the name you have but without the `.mustache` that will be added by the `ViewResolver`.

So in short you should remove things and it will work. Do more with less in this case.